# Jenkins integration with RCP product

Tags: jenkins, eclipse-rcp, mylyn, jenkins-api

I have an RCP product with a view. In the view, i want to show all the jenkins builds configured and should be able to download builds, view logs, trigger builds. is there any API available?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search yielded the following result [Jenkins Remote API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). The sample code section has some details. Hope this helps